# Installing Python package in offline environment does not find installed dependency

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am trying to install the SQLACodegen package and its dependencies (inflect, setuptools-scm) from source, in an offline environment. Specifically, I have an Anaconda 2020.07 install using Python 3.8, on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 system.

I have the Anaconda bin directory prepended to PATH, and I install using `python -m pip install whatever.tar.gz`. Yes, I know it's a sin to use `pip` over `conda` like this. It just so happens that this is the easier way about things when installing upstream packages and I've never had an issue installing many other packages before now.

The problem is that pip is trying to go out to the internet to download and install `setuptools`. The strange part is that setuptools is already installed and meets the version requirements of the package. Even when I specify pip flags such as `--no-index -f /path/to/packages`, it still fails to detect the installed setuptools and tries to pull it from somewhere.

Example output:

```
[root@myserver stuff]# ls
inflect-4.1.0.tar.gz  setuptools_scm-4.1.2.tar.gz  sqlacodegen-2.1.0.tar.gz
[root@myserver stuff]# which python
/usr/local/anaconda-2020.07/bin/python
[root@myserver stuff]# python -V
Python 3.8.3
[root@myserver stuff]# python -m pip list | grep setuptools
setuptools                             49.2.0.post20200714
[root@myserver stuff]# python -m pip install --no-index -f . sqlacodegen-2.1.0.tar.gz
Looking in links: .
Processing ./sqlacodegen-2.1.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/anaconda-2020.07/bin/python /usr/local/anaconda-2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env/r61p50oe/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links . -- 'setuptools >= 36.2.7' wheel 'setuptools_scm >= 1.7.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (3 lines):
  Looking in links: .
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=36.2.7 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=36.2.7
```

I have a feeling the `--ignore-installed` flag might be part of the problem, but I don't know how to override it, it looks like pip slaps on numerous options on its own. Has anyone encountered a similar situation and resolved it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `install` option [`--no-build-isolation`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-build-isolation) when installing from source and you want to tell Pip to make use of already installed packages to satisfy the build dependencies. Emphasis on *build* dependencies.

The most common build dependencies, according to [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#build-system-table), are `setuptools` and `wheel`. So much so that, as the "minimum requirements for the build system to execute", build tools are expected to add them tacitly to a build configuration.

When installing a new package from source, packages in the Python environment are ignored as far as build dependencies are concerned. As the [Pip documentation explains](http://web.archive.org/web/20210518140230/https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#pep-517-and-518-support):

> When making build requirements available, pip does so in an *isolated environment*. That is, pip does not install those requirements into the user’s `site-packages`, but rather installs them in a temporary directory which it adds to the user’s `sys.path` for the duration of the build. This ensures that build requirements are handled independently of the user’s runtime environment. For example, a project that needs a recent version of setuptools to build can still be installed, even if the user has an older version installed (and without silently replacing that version).

(The documentation has since been updated and rephrased, see section [Build Process](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/?highlight=isolated%20environment#build-process), and no longer mentions explicitly that `site-packages` will be ignored, though that's still implied.)

In your example, that temporary directory seems to be `/tmp/pip-build-env/r61p50oe`. Instead of the `--no-build-isolation` option, you could also add the source packages of `setuptools` and `wheel` (possibly more, depending on the package you're installing) to the local folder specified via the `-f`/`--find-links` option.